# Use a variable in different classes in webforms c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, variables, webforms

I am stack in something simple i think.

I have the following code:

```
public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "text/xml")
            {

                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.ReadXml((Server.MapPath(filename)));
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Only xml files are accepted!";

    }
}

public void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

What i want is the user the execute this code in button2

```
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.ReadXml((Server.MapPath(filename)));
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

My problem is that the variable filename is not available outside

```
public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Chris

Comment: those are NOT different classes, those are different methods of same class / web form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the filename into `Session` or `ViewState` while uploading a file.

```
public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ..
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    ...
    Session["filename"]=filename;
}
```

Code in Button2 click handler,

```
public void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(Session["filename"]!=null)
 { 
  string filename=Session["filename"].ToString();
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ds.ReadXml((Server.MapPath("~/" + filename)));
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: if the value is needed only in that page I would NOT use the Session.

Answer (score 2):

you can persist the variable in the page ViewState like this:

```
private string fileName
{
    get { return ViewState["fileName"] != null ? (string)ViewState["fileName"] : String.Empty; }
    set { ViewState["fileName"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually here you can have huge amount of variants:

1. You can get this value from file upload control, juts simply using same method as it was used in Button1Click:

   ```
   string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
   ```
2. More correctly, is to store in ViewState as it was told before.
3. If you want to use this in other pages, just save this to session.